# How to control select box's choices in Vuetify.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using Vuetify.js in my work and my framework is Nuxt.js and Typescript.
I want to change select box choice's when I choose one.
So I tried to make test code below.
If I choose some state in select box, state will display to text-field.
And then I choose again other state in select box, I only choose not selected.
It means if I choose the state, next time selected state is not displayed in select box.
I don't know how to create that kind of function.
Could someone advise me,please?
My sample wrote in codepen and checked operation.

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-subheader>Custom items</v-subheader>
        </v-col>
  
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-select
            v-model="select"
            :hint="`${select.state}, ${select.abbr}`"
            :items="items"
            item-text="state"
            item-value="abbr"
            label="Select"
            persistent-hint
            return-object
            single-line
          ></v-select>
          <v-text-field v-model="select.state"></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      select: { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
      items: [
        { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
        { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
        { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to create any function. Please look in [Vuetify select documentation on API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#api)

There in props section you will find prop **hide-selected** which actually do what you want to achive